# How to link to `this` textfield in print when expression?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to change the visibility of a large number of fields (30 or more..)

Is it possible to refer `this` in the field expression, or something like that?

For example, I have many numeric fields like this :

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.00#">
    <reportElement x="329" y="4" width="49" height="18">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{myNumeric}>0]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
        <font fontName="DejaVu Serif"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myNumeric}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Can I change `printWhenExpression` to something like this?

```
this.field.getValue()>0 //field is the textField
```

Is this possible or is it impossible in principle? Maybe there are utility class?

Comment: `this.field.getValue()>0` - What is `this` in your pseudocode expression? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I mean this text field. The field from where expression called.

Comment: I think it is impossible to write something like you want without changing the engine's source code

Comment: Benefits - I don't need to set `printWhenExpression` for each field, for example : myNumeric - $F{myNumeric}>0, myNumeric2 - $F{myNumeric2}>0, just one expression for all fields.

Comment: You have to change the JR source code. Or you can use JR API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **not** reefer to the textField and it's value directly in the `printWhenExpression`

The only "similar" method you can use, is to return `null` values when you do not like to display the textField setting these 2 properties:

> **isRemoveLineWhenBlank**, remove if empty

with

> **isBlankWhenNull**, if null replace with empty string

**Example** (textField below will not display if `$F{myNumeric}<0`)

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true" pattern="#,##0.00#">
    <reportElement x="329" y="4" width="49" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
        <font fontName="DejaVu Serif"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myNumeric}>0?$F{myNumeric}:null]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Add some logic to your datasource (query/custom), to return `null` values if `<0` and you will not need the ternary operator in expression.

**Note:** `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` will also have effect on your other components in report if they have position type `float`